# how to put the tabs on bottom using tabHost

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-service

I wanted to do some changes in the given XML file so that the tabs must display on bottom.

The XML file of the tabHost Activity is given Below. The o/p ( graphical view ) is also given.

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".TabHostActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/activity_tab_host_llLeftFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/activity_tab_host_llRegFormFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/activity_tab_host_llRightFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        
        <FrameLayout 
            android:id="@+id/activity_tab_host_llDisplayDataFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

and the the graphical View of this is given below

I Want to put that tab on bottom .. I tried a lot but didn't found any solution.

Please help.

[image: this the the o/p]

Comment: used `RelativeLayout` and set ` android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` to your `TabWidget`

Comment: -1 for not doing some research first ... fx: google.com would return many answer for this question

Comment: @Selvin I have done research on this issue ... The ans I find is for Relative layout .. But That shows some problem ... I want changes in my XML file...

Comment: +1 for this there is nothing on Google like this for linear layout. all Google returns are for relative layout!!! this question needs +1 !!! @Selvin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp" >


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_tab1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_tab2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_tab3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" />
        </FrameLayout>
         <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_weight="0"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

update your layout.xml file with this code you will get the desired output!!!

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution used `RelativeLayout` and set `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` to your **TabWidget**

```
   .........
   <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
     ..........
   </RelativeLayout>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: I know this method with relative layout... I want to do some changes in my code and put my tab down...

Answer (score 2):

For Bottom Tabs:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"  //<----IMPORTANT
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</TabHost>
```